# View source not showing current gridview. What's happening here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, gridview, view-source

Using aspnet, c# 3.5, developing in vs2008. Using IE7.

I have a web page consisting of a dropdown list and a gridview. The contents of the gridview are mostly dynamically generated in the code behind.

When the app runs, the default value for the contents of the gridview are displayed on the page, and can be seen in the viewsource.

When a selection is chosen from the dropdownlist, the gridview contents is rebound to different data, all the dynamic fields and controls are recalculated and populated, and the web page is displayed with the new data in the browser.

But if I look at view source, the html table into which the gridview has been rendered still shows the original data.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you updating the form with AJAX (an update panel, or something perhaps)?

If so I recommend downloading the IE dev toolbar (which is installed by default in IE8) and using that to view the source - you should see the updated content